# array = np.int(array) TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, math

```
array = df.as_matrix()
array = np.int(array)
```

I tried:

```
array = np.int(array)
```

for :

```
array[i][10]/5
```

but got :

> array = np.int(array) TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars????

Comment: Use `array.astype(int)`.

Comment: `np.int` is the same as the base Python `int`, a function that creates a (one) integer from a number or string.  It does not convert an array (or list or string of multiple numbers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
>>> a = np.random.normal(20, 5, size=(2,2))
array([[ 24.04255462,  24.24954137],
       [ 14.64894245,  16.17946985]])
>>> a = a.astype(int)
>>> a
array([[24, 24],
       [14, 16]])
```

Check the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html).